# How to direct terminal command real-time output to webpage running on localhost written in golang?

Tags: go, webserver, real-time, stdout, httphandler

I relatively new to golang, and I am currently running into an issue of redirecting my terminal output to my webpage running on localhost. In golang, I have written a webserver running on localhost with a html button on it. When clicked, the button will execute the following terminal command:

```
sudo nmap -F -sS X.X.X.0/24 --stats-every 2s | grep --line-buffered 'Ping Scan Timing' | awk '{print $5}'
```

This outputs the execution time of the command every 2s to my os.stdout terminal. The output looks something like this:

```
10%
15%
30%
.
.
.
```

But now I have modified my code because I am trying to redirect this output to my webpage, and render it in realtime, so that it I can see how much progress is left for the execution to be completed since this command can take a while to load.

The problem I am running into is that I cannot properly use the stdoutpipe function to redirect the output to my webpage. Here is a snippet of my code for the handler that gets triggered when I click the button in my webpage:

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, ok := w.(http.Flusher)

    if !ok {
            http.Error(w, "Oops", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)


    nmap_chain := "nmap -F -sS X.X.X.0/24 -oX output.xml --stats-every 2s | grep --line-buffered 'Ping Scan Timing' | awk '{print $5}'"
    cmd := exec.Command("bash","-c",nmap_chain)
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    in := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

    for in.Scan() {
            fmt.Fprintf(w,"%d\n\n",in) 
            conn.Flush()
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

    if err := in.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: %s", err)
    }


}
```

My html file looks like the following as well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NMAP Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout/mystyle.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#exec").on("click", function() {
  $('#exec').prop('disabled', true);
                $.ajax({
      url: "/exec",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
      $("#response").html(data);
      $('#exec').prop('disabled', false);
      },
         });
     });
 });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerBar"></div>
    <div>
        <button id="exec">Execute Command</button>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
        <textarea readonly id="response" rows="50" cols="50" style="resize"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As of right now, I cannot see any output in my html textarea when this handler is executed. I've also tried creating a basic function that would execute the nmap command mentioned, and redirect the output to a log instead of os.stdout using stdoutpipe. But still I cannot see any output.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The ajax call will not complete until the handler returns.  Use [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) or [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).  Here's [an example showing how to pipe the output of a command through a websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/command).